# Fixture "setUp" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

**Commandline**

> python3 -m pytest src/spec/ --app=android

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--app')

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--app")
```

**driver.py**

```
import pytest

class Driver(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, driver)

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setUp(self, app):
        self.app = app

        if self.app == 'ios':
            desired_caps = {}
            desired_caps['platformName'] = 'ios'
            desired_caps['platformVersion'] = ''
            desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'PF'

        elif self.app == 'android':
            desired_caps = {}
            desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
            desired_caps['platformVersion'] = ''
            desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'PF'
            desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.wdiodemoapp'
            desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.wdiodemoapp.MainActivity'

        self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub", desired_caps)
```

[image]

Comment: If nothing else you got me really curious about your motivation to mix together `unittest.TestCase` and pytest's fixtures.

Comment: You have not posted the test function(s) but it looks like you are calling the fixture like `setup()` instead of using it like `setup`. Or, if the `setup` fixture does not return anything, then you can avoid using it in the test function (it is already set for autouse).

Comment: @tmt I used unittest -based test suites to use pytest as a test runner; on the way, I like the pytest fixtures too and I wish to use them. Is there a possible fix for the issue I face

Comment: I think that your issue is that pytest expects to be the sole manager of fixtures and their invocation (based on scope, autouse, etc.) while `unittest.TestCase` calls `setUp` method [automatically](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) as well. So I don't think that `setUp` should be a fixture.

Comment: @tmt, yeniv both are right; it is because of the native unittest.TestCase setUp(). I fixed it by calling it in a separate method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is cos of mixing up of `unittest` with `pytest`. The below fixed it.

```
def setUp(self):
   Driver.fix

   if self.app == 'ios':
      desired_caps = {}
      desired_caps['platformName'] = 'ios'
      desired_caps['platformVersion'] = ''
      desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'PF'

   elif self.app == 'android':
      desired_caps = {}
      desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
      desired_caps['platformVersion'] = ''
      desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'PF'
      desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.wdiodemoapp'
      desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.wdiodemoapp.MainActivity'

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def fix(self, app):
   self.app = app
```