# Fixtures are not meant to be called directly

Tags: django, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures, django-testing

I'm using **Django 3.0.5**, **pytest 5.4.1** and **pytest-django 3.9.0**. I want to create a fixture that returns a *User* object to use in my tests.
Here is my **conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


@pytest.fixture
def create_user(db):
    return get_user_model().objects.create_user('user@gmail.com', 'password')
```

Here is my **api_students_tests.py**

```
import pytest
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIClient


    class StudentViewTests(APITestCase):

        user = None

        @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
        def setUp(self, create_user):
            self.user = create_user

        def test_create_student(self):
            assert self.user.email == 'user@gmail.com'  
            # other stuff ...
```

I keep getting the following error

```
Fixture "setUp" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
```

I read and read again [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884245/fixture-setup-called-directly-fixtures-are-not-meant-to-be-called-directly) but I cannot find out a solution. Furthermore, in that question the fixture wasn't returning nothing, while in my case it should return an object (don't know if it can make any difference)

Comment: You should use pytest fixtures or UnitTest setUp functions. There is no point in using both. (ps: use example.com as a domain for testing etc.)

Comment: @thebjorn sorry, I think I still miss something. So I have two options: 1 --> use a fixture to create a User; 2 --> create that User in the **setUp** method. Correct? But in case of option #2, I should rewrite the same code for each tests in which I need a User object, shouldn' t I? There's no way to reuse the logic to create a User inside setUp without rewrite it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the `setUp`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def create_user(db):
    return get_user_model().objects.create_user('user@gmail.com', 'password')


class StudentViewTests(APITestCase):

    def test_create_student(self, create_user):
        assert user.email == 'user@gmail.com'  
        # other stuff ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work, failed with the following error                                                                                                            
`FAILED errepiuapp/tests/mock_tests.py::StudentViewTests::test_create_student - TypeError: test_create_student() missing 1 required positional argument: 'create_user'
`

Comment: how are you running your tests?

Comment: I've copied your snippet into a file, then I've run `pytest -vs`

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: Should be assert create_user.email == 'user@gmail.com'